# Touchpad doesn't work on Fujitsu Lifebook UH552

Tags: gnome, grub2, touchpad, input-devices

Recently I bought the laptop with pre-installed Win8 and tried to insall Ubuntu 13.04 beside it.
I have to say, that the installation was fine, but then some strange things began to happen: first booting Ubuntu I saw that there like was no desktop enviroment, so the windows did not have title bars, panels did not exis. I installed Gnome-fallback.

On startup, each time I see

```
 psmouse 'raw' is invalid parameter for 'proto'
```

driver is installed

```
$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... Done
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics is already the newest version.
```

Add lines `"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX =" i8042.notimeout i8042.nomux "` in the / etc / default / grub does not work

Can anybody tell me what to do?

Comment: You can install metacity `sudo apt-get install metacity` then run it `metacity --replace &`. This will give you window borders and titles. For further help, read [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers/61433#61433).

Comment: to be honest, my video card is Intel4000 and I don't feell like having troubles with it. I'd be glad to hear sth about touchpad, that, I believe is not by any way connected to the video card. Either way, thanks.

Comment: Well, in Ubuntu everything is connected. I guessed if Unity does not work that something wrong with Compiz. Compiz depends on xorg configuration and loaded kernel modules. And xorg configuration affects also input devices. So if you want understand what's wrong with touchpad, you have to find out why Unity doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, guys, I made it. Just like [Danatela](https://askubuntu.com/users/171636/danatela) said, everything is connected. I had troubles with my newly installed Ubuntu because of incorrect instalation, so I reinstalled the OS and added `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.notimeout i8042.nomux"` to the `/etc/default/grub`.

And it works!